# Importing Database Using Symfony2 and Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to use the command

```
doctrine:mapping:import
```

to import a database into my project, However I do not want the database.orm.yml files to be in a Bundle I want to have the orm and Entity files located in a Static directory in my src folder. The command above requires me to provide a bundle name. My question is, **how do I import the mapping file into the folder `./src/Entity/orm` folder and not into a Bundle?** Is this even possible?

```
./src/Entity/orm        <-- Directory having the .yml files
./src/Entity/Repository <-- The repository classes
./src/Entity            <-- The Entity Classes here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question with what I found to work.

The following command will generate entities from the database into a specified file and adding the namespace to the classes;

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src/Entity --from-database --force --namespace="Entity\\";
```

For a complete answer, I could have used:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src/Entity --from-database --force --namespace="Entity\\";
```

to generate the yaml orm files. then manually added the namespace to each one followed by running:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities ./src/Entity/orm
```

after setting up the Symfony2 config.yml parameters correctly. However, that would have been a wasted effort since I can just as easily use annotations.

What I learned from this experience is that using yaml orm files and generating entities is a nice feature, if you are using a code first development strategy. If you are just trying to generate an Entity Framework from a poorly designed or bloated database as I am, using annotations saves a headache.

Now what I am doing since you cannot specify repositoryClasses from the database. Is just adding repository classes as I develop. Not every one of the 200+ tables needs a repository class.

**Note:** This database was not designed "in house" and the common consensus is that it is terrible and needs redesign, but current time constraints are not allowing us to do that...